# Keras ValueError : the Dens' input dimension should be defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to use VGG16 with some modification on it. I followed this [blog post](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) from keras.io

Here the code I'm using to create the model:

```
def create_model():

    vgg16_model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    
    print('[INFO] Model loaded.')

    x = vgg16_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=vgg16_model.inputs, outputs=x)
    return model
```

Calling the `model = create_model()` gives an error:

> ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Question is incomplete, Where is the error raised?

Comment: @SayanDey It is raised when I call the `create_model()`  func. It's in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass an `input_shape` when you use the `vgg16.VGG16`

```
def create_model():

    vgg16_model = vgg16.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    
    print('[INFO] Model loaded.')

    x = vgg16_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)

    model = Model(inputs=vgg16_model.inputs, outputs=x)
    return model
```

Comment: because if u don't specify the shape the output of your flatten layer is (None,None) which raises an error in the following dense layer (The last dimension of the inputs to Dense should be defined)... don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you take a look at my previous post, it's somehow related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719346/how-to-resolve-the-resourceexhaustederror-oom-when-allocating-tensor